# I am trying to execute the following query but got (Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ID, loan_num, borrower_name, loan_type, 
       (select document_name AS docs_uploaded 
        FROM document_list 
        WHERE document_list.document_id IN (closing_docs.docs_uploaded)), 
        docs_exceptions 
FROM closing_docs ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Give some suggestions for above query.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `mysqli` specifically, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: The error cannot be more descriptive about what is wrong.

Comment: It may be that the sub query could be replaced by a join but without sample data and expected output it's not possible to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, loan_num, borrower_name, loan_type, 
       (select document_name AS docs_uploaded 
        FROM document_list 
        WHERE document_list.document_id IN (closing_docs.docs_uploaded)
        LIMIT 1 ), 
        docs_exceptions 
FROM closing_docs ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Using LIMIT 1 ensures only one row is returned from sub query but i am not sure whether this is what you want.
Also below line does not look ok.

```
WHERE document_list.document_id IN (closing_docs.docs_uploaded)
```

Comment: Only if this is what the user want in output. Orherwise this will only resolve thr runtime error

Comment: TOP is sql server MYSQL equivalent is LIMIT

Comment: I have many "document_id"s in each row of table "closing_docs" and table "document_list" has "document_name" for each "document_id". I want to show the "document_name" for each "document_id" in "docs_exceptions" column of table "closing_docs".